# csapp ./dlc: cannot execute binary file on macos

Tags: c, macos, unix

I have these files on my dir

```
Driverhdrs.pm 
README 
btest.c 
dlc 
ishow.c 
Driverlib.pm 
bits.c 
btest.h 
driver.pl 
tests.c 
Makefile 
bits.h 
decl.c 
fshow.c
```

By following the instruction, I type `./dlc bits.c` on terminal, but I get `./dlc: cannot execute binary file on macos`. I look up the solution online and find that I need to execute on the right OS. However, I have no idea how this works. I also try to compile dlc again, but I do not have the source code.

Could someone please tell me the specific steps on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you see when you run `file dlc`?  I suspect you don't see `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64` — you see some other binary information for some other O/S.  If I'm right, you'll need to recompile the program on the Mac.

Comment: The list of files includes a `Makefile` — have you run `make`?  The presence of two `.pm` files is intriguing; this looks a bit like it might be a Perl module.

Comment: when I run ```file dlc``` I get ```dlc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=b91ebfc2c7c563e423668001e1131530358033cb, with debug_info, not stripped```, but I don't know how to recompile it without .c file.

Comment: I ran ```make``` before

Comment: If neither `make` nor `make dlc` makes, you will have to research where the source code is. What you’ve got is a Linux binary; it won’t run on macOS.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/jerrylzy/CS33/tree/master/Lab/datalab) the code you're trying to run?  It looks like it's a Linux binary to test your code, and they've intentionally omitted the source code (so that you can't easily see the test cases that are actually being run).  As such, you won't be able to run this on your Mac; you will need to find or create a Linux machine (possibly virtual) in order to do it.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212754/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-linux-binary-on-macos